# Utilizing %r within raw_input in python

Tags: python, raw-input

Is it feasible to utilize %r within raw_input in python?

For context, I'm working on Zed Shaw's [Exercise 12](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex12.html).  (Great resource!  The lessons are very helpful, and well paced.)

I'm playing around in the extra credit, trying to get raw_input to repeat what I typed in.  I know I can accomplish the same thing with a print statement, but am curious if I can accomplish it within raw_input.

The code I'm typing is:

```
from sys import argv

script, firstname, lastname = argv

age = raw_input("Hello %r, what is your age? ") % firstname

print ("Ahh, Mr. %r, you are %r years old.") % (lastname, age)
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex13a.py", line 5, in <module>
    age = raw_input("Hello %r, what is your age? ") % firstname
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `age = raw_input("Hello %r, what is your age? " % firstname)`

Comment: Type `%r` as input to the question and you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your line should read

```
raw_input("Hello %r, what is your age? " % firstname)
```

instead of

```
raw_input("Hello %r, what is your age? ") % firstname
```

---

Otherwise, you would not format your `"Hello %r, ..."` string, but the resulting string of the call to `raw_input`.